# Disable freemarker logs

Tags: struts2, freemarker

I'm using Struts 2.0.11.2 and I don't what was changed recently in my app that I get TONS of freemarker logs:

```
DEBUG   13201   [freemark] (): template/simple/hidden.ftl[en,UTF-8,parsed] cached copy not yet stale; using cached.
```

How can I turn off these annoying logs? I know of the freemarker.properties file but I don't find how to specify log levels from there. I tried the hack in my code:

```
freemarker.log.Logger.selectLoggerLibrary(freemarker.log.Logger.LIBRARY_NONE);
```

and for some people it doesn't work. I'm not using log4j, just standard java logging.

By the way: I'm not planning to change the Struts version or the logging framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Weblogic you can disable the debug messages with a LogFilter as described here: http://blog.technogemsinc.com/2012/09/weblogic-disabling-freemark-debug.html.

Answer (score 0):

Look where you configure java.util.logging (or commons logging maybe). If the logger says that it logs debug-level messages from FreeMaker, FreeMarker will send debug-level messages. This is just like with any other library.

Disabling FreeMarker logging is certainly not a good idea, as you want to see the warnings and errors. (The reasons `LIBRARY_NONE` doesn't work is certainly that you call it too late, when some messages was already logged, and thus FreeMarker logging was already initialized.)

Comment: I configure java.util.logging in the JRE logging.properties file itself, it doesn't log things below INFO by default. Anyway, some people is still seeing the logs, some are not. I think it logs something before the LIBRARY_NONE just in some systems

Comment: If you have Log4j 1.x in your classpath, FreeMarker will use that, not `java.util.logging`, so `logging.properties` won't mater. If setting the `org.freemarker.loggerLibrary` system property to `JUL` fixes the issue (requires FreeMarker 2.3.22), then the issue is clearly that: you need to configure Log4j too. Or better yet, migrate to SLF4J if you can... if FreeMarker 2.3.22 finds `log4j-over-slf4j` in the classpath, it will use SLF4J instead of anything else.