# Disable freemarker logs from logs4j

Tags: struts2, freemarker, log4j2

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971421/disable-freemarker-logs) but i'm using log4j2.

I need a way to disable All logs from freemarker, in their [documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_logging.html) they say we can do it by calling `Logger.selectLoggerLibrary(Logger.LIBRARY_NONE)` but they say

> selectLoggerLibrary must be called early, before FreeMarker could log anything, or else it will not have (consistent) effect.

Where do I call this in a struts2 application? (I tried calling it in `prepare()` method in my action class but its not working.) or is there any other way to disable the logs?

Comment: I know its very late, it may help someone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794195/struts2-logs-disabling-from-log4j-properties-file/51010631#51010631

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question is, why do you need to disable it like that?

You shouldn't need that, so I guess that's where the real problem lies. Is there some kind of malfunction? Because if there isn't, why not just set the `freemarker` logger category to be ignored in your logger configuration? That's the normal way of doing this, FreeMarker or not.

Anyway, in 2.3.22 (release expected in early 2015) you can use the `-Dorg.freemarker.loggerLibrary=none` where you start the JVM (that is, you set the `org.freemarker.loggerLibrary` system property). Otherwise, if you could call that method in a `ServletContextListener` that's certainly early enough.

**Update:**

Reacting to the comments... in most applications you will have 3rd party libraries that use various logging "frameworks", like SLF4J, commons-logging, JUL, Log4j, Log4j2. Thus you have to ensure that all these get redirected into the same logger library, which is certainly Log4j2 in your case. I suspect that wasn't properly done in your case, so now multiple logger libraries log to the console, each with its own configuration settings.

FreeMarker 2.3.x uses Log4j 1.x if it detects that `org.apache.log4j.Logger` is present. Other logger libraries that it also can detect and use (Log4j2 is not amongst them) have lower priority. (FreeMarker 2.4.x will always use SLF4J if it's present.) Thus, if you add `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api` to your dependencies, then FM will use `org.apache.log4j.Logger`, and so `log4j-1.2.-api` will redirect the FM log messages to Log4j2. That worked for me, with this Log4j2 configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </Root>
    <Logger name="freemarker" level="off">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </Logger>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Um... If you guys need a solution, then maybe you should elaborate on what the problem is, instead of just down voting. And, if it's a bug, or some kind of incompatibility, I might as well can fix it.

Comment: Thanks! calling from `ServletContextListener` worked. Dont know why, but I cant configure it in log4j2.xml that it should be ignored, tried each thing that i found online. sounds like freemarker ignores my log4j2's configuration... so disabling from `ServletContextListener` is the only option so far.

Comment: Woops! First time i saw the answer was from the mobile app, i saw it has one downvote, now from desktop i want to accept the answer and upvote, i see that i was the downvote, it was for sure a mistake, but it wont let me upvote or remove it, cuz its after 3 hours...

Comment: @ElyeM. now you can turn your downvote into an upvote (you can revert/remove old votes with an edit of the post)... and +1 to ddekany for maintaining FreeMarker :)

Comment: Thanks, upvoted, @ddekany have you configured once FreemMaker with log4j2.xml so the logs should be ignored? I would rather do it there, but its not working.

Comment: Do the log messages show up in a log file that was configured in Log4j2, or somewhere else? FreeMarker doesn't know log4j*2*, so it must have chosen another logger, perhaps log4j 1.x if that's around, otherwise `java.util.Logging`. (In general, I would recommend `log4j-over-slf4j` to be present, and then just using SLF4J as usual. 2.3.22 even switches to clean SLF4J API usage if it detects these two.)

Comment: @ddekany I set it up it should log to the console, and I tried to exclude FreeMarker from the logs, apparently it didn't work,  so you saying if I'm using log4j2 there isn't any way to configure so it shouldn't log. Right?

Answer (score 0):

This came up as the first search result for "disable freemarker logging" which I searched for because I got double error logs for template errors, one from within the Freemarker library and one from my own code catching the same exception and logging it. The solution to this is simple and different from the answers already given: call [`setLogTemplateExceptions(false)`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/Configuration.html#setLogTemplateExceptions-boolean-) on the Freemarker Configuration. In full:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_31);
configuration.setLogTemplateExceptions(false);
```

The default behavior of logging the exception even though it propagates out of the Freemarker library is mentioned as a quirk on the [Freemarker Logging documentation](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_misc_logging.html).

Answer (score -1):

Use this statement:

```
freemarker.log.Logger.selectLoggerLibrary(freemarker.log.Logger.LIBRARY_NONE);
```

Comment: This was deprecated. Can you provide the updated code?