# Disabling debug logging for freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I'm using freemarker to generate emails that are being sent automatically to the users of a web app we're creating. Currently there are a lot of debug statements being generated by freemarker, and when the app goes live the log files will be filled with a bunch of info we don't really want to keep track of. So, how can I turn off all logging for freemarker?

We're developing in JDeveloper 11.1.1.9.0, using WebLogic 10.3.

I've tried looking online, at the below in particular, but to no avail. http://freemarker.624813.n4.nabble.com/disable-logging-td626241.html
[Disable freemarker logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971421/disable-freemarker-logs)

[image]

Comment: What's a log level of those log statements? Can you show examples of redundant logs entries?  (BTW, the official documentation regarding logging is here: http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_logging.html)

Comment: @ddekany edited the post to include a screenshot of an instance of the logs

Comment: On the screenshot those are all `DEBUG` level log entries, so based on that there's nothing to configure in FreeMarker. You have to raise the logging level in your runtime environment to INFO or WARN, as it's usual for production environments. Even in development mode, DEBUG should only be used for the categories that belong to your code.

Comment: Since this was written some time ago, is there anyone that knows if this have changed by now? Changing logging properties will not do any good here I am afraid, since this would be a legacy breaker for the project I work in. @ddekany Any more info? As far as I can see this have not changed in any major way since then. It might possibly work to hard code a few exceptions in my log configuration, but nothing else than that.

Comment: @patrik Frankly, I don't see what the problem to fix is. Setting log levels is up to the logging framework, and that's like so in all other Java libraries/frameworks as well. In any logging framework I know of, you can set log levels per log category. So, set the logging level to `WARN` (or `ERROR`, or `INFO`) for the `freemarker` category in the log configuration. It won't influence the log level of any other components, so it shouldn't break that legacy system.

Comment: @ddekany We are not allowed to add any logging configuration to the framework I work with. It is not possible to add this to the test folder either, to get rid of these logs, since freemarker is used during maven compile.

Comment: DEBUG is just a wrong default for a framework, and I will be surprised if only FreeMarker logs a lot with that level. Report it to them if you can: default should be INFO or WARN. Anyway, what are the things that you can do? Like, can you configure FreeMarker in Java? Can you set system properties before the application starts?